# stream to write to a file as well as write to a string variable

Tags: c++, file-handling, stringstream, ofstream, ostream

I am trying a scenario where in a function it puts data to a file.

```
func(std::ofstream fileStream, JsonData)
{
parses the Json and does some logic and puts to fil stream
}
std::ofstream fileStream(filename);
func(fileStream, jsonData);
//want a scenario where std::string aa will get values in ofstream.
fileStream.close();
```

Could anyone please help me out if I can convert the stream data to std::string?
I saw that ostream can be converted to stringstream; and that can be move to std::string ; but unable to open a file with ostream.

Please help me out...

Comment: Is there a reason you can't pipe everything into a string stream, get a string, then write that string to a file?

Comment: Please post real code. `func(std::ofstream fileStream, JsonData)` tries to pass an `ofstream` by value, which is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
func(std::ofstream fileStream, JsonData)
{
parses the Json and does some logic and puts to fil stream
}
```

To be

```
func(std::ostream& Stream, JsonData)
{
    //parses the Json and does some logic and puts to fill Stream
}
```

And now what you can do is pass a `stringstream` to the function and have that get filled.  Then you can get a string out of it, and pass it's buffer to an ofstream like

```
JsonData data;
std::stringstream ss;
// populate string stream
func(ss, data); 
// get string
std::string stringifiedData = ss.str();
// open file
std::ofstream fileStream(filename);
// write to file
fileStream << ss.rdbuf();
```